# Calculate last days of months for given period in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to do in SQL: for example I have period `where @s_date = '20130101' and @e_date = '20130601'` and I want to select all last days of months in this period.

This is example of result:

```
20130131
20130228
20130331
20130430
20130531
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your version of MSSQL, because in 2012 you can use Emonth() function

Comment: I am using SQL-SERVER 2008 and there's not such function. But can i use this function for period or it works only for one date? because i have equal function of EMONTH in SQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is to have a [calendar table](http://blog.jontav.com/post/9380766884/calendar-tables-are-incredibly-useful-in-sql), with a last day of the month flag, so your query would simply be:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    dbo.Calendar
WHERE   Date >= @StartDate
AND     Date <= @EndDate
AND     EndOfMonth = 1;
```

Assuming of course that you don't have a calendar table you can generate a list of dates on the fly:'

```
DECLARE @s_date DATE = '20130101',
        @e_date DATE = '20130601';

SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Object_ID) - 1, @s_date)
FROM    sys.all_objects;
```

Then once you have your dates you can limit them to where the date is the last day of the month (where adding one day makes it the first of the month):

```
DECLARE @s_date DATE = '20130101',
        @e_date DATE = '20130601';

WITH Dates AS
(   SELECT  Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Object_ID) - 1, @s_date)
    FROM    sys.all_objects
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Dates
WHERE   Date <= @e_Date
AND     DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date)) = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13234)**

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following query and then adjust it by using your table details:

```
declare @s_date as datetime= '20130101'
declare @e_date as datetime= '20131020'


SELECT DateAdd(m, number, '1990-01-31')
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE  'P' = type
AND DateAdd(m, number, @s_date) < @e_date
```

Answer (score 0):

example for `20130101` :

```
select  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 
            dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, 1, 
                  convert(datetime, '20130101',112))), 112)
```

result :

20130131

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
WITH sample 
     AS (SELECT Cast('2013-04-01' AS DATETIME) Date 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Dateadd(day, 1, date) dt 
         FROM   sample 
         WHERE  date < Cast('2013-05-05' AS DATETIME)) 
SELECT * 
FROM   sample
```

### [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/13236)

Comment: This returns all dates, not just the last day of the month as described in the question. Also, not really significant for such a small set, but using a recursive CTE [to generate a sequential list](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2) is also the least efficient method of doing so (with the exception of possibly a while loop). So even though not significant in this case it is probably good to get out of the habit.

Answer (score 0):

EOMONTH(@date) is the function you need.
Here is the help page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

This query gets the las 50 End Of Months.
The original query used as an example is from here.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/186829

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) - 1 AS [Incrementor]
  FROM   [master].[sys].[columns] sc1
  CROSS JOIN [master].[sys].[columns] sc2
)
SELECT top 50 EOMONTH(DATEADD(Month, -1 * cte.[Incrementor], GETDATE()))
FROM   cte
WHERE  EOMONTH(DATEADD(Month, -1 * cte.[Incrementor], GETDATE())) < GETDATE();
```